Android Java PTT Button on CAT42 H+
I would like to assign the PTT button in a Java app on a Caterpillar CAT 42 H+. Does anyone know of an event/listener that makes this possible.
I have not found any solution for the CAT42 H+. I found instructions for other manufacturers but not for Caterpillar.
